# SQL Server hangs querying 2 independent tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am querying 2 independent tables but related data.

The query is as follows:

```
select 
    STDEV(M1.[Close]) as M1, STDEV(M2.[Close]) as M2 
from 
    M1, M2;
```

I want to show 2 standard deviation data on separate columns.

But SQL Server hangs there and stops moving. Why is that? It is a very simple query.

How can I do so without crossing 2 tables? The tables are huge.

Comment: You're doing a huge cross-product here.

Comment: Why not UNION ALL instead? Or select sub-queries.

Comment: You're performing a `CROSS JOIN` on the tables, which you say are "huge" (not that that has much meaning). If they really are *huge* (millions of rows in each?), then of course it's going to take a long time. If, for example,each table had as little as 100,000 rows each you would be creating 10,000,000,000 (100,000²) rows!

Comment: Thanks for answering
Union will not combine the data?

Comment: if from A,B equals A cross join B, then why
select STDEV(M1.[Close]) as M1 from M1, M2;
can be processed very quickly?

Comment: *"Union will not combine the data?"* `UNION (ALL)` queries combine 2 result sets with the same definitions into one.

Comment: *"can be processed very quickly"* it won't be if you're asking for billions of rows... Like I said, even if the tables have as few as 100,000 rows each, a `CROSS JOIN` would result in a final database of 10 Billion rows. That really ***is*** a **huge** dataset.

Comment: the results of the following queries are completely different

select STDEV(M1.[Close]) as M1 from M1, M2; Quick

select STDEV(M1.[Close]) as M1, STDEV(M2.[Close]) as M2 from M1, M2; Hangs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use this.

```
 SELECT 
   (SELECT STDEV(M1.[Close]) from M1) as M1 , 
   (SELECT STDEV(M2.[Close]) from M2) as M2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Cross joins on big tables can have that effect on performance.
Although there are some rare situations where they are useful, it's best to avoid them.

Serkan's answer that uses 2 nested sub-queries is the best solution for this question.
Short and easy to understand.

But to get a result from 2 unrelated tables, one could also use UNION ALL with placeholder values.

```
SELECT
 SUM(StddevM1) AS M1,
 SUM(StddevM2) AS M2
FROM
(
    SELECT STDEV(M1.Close) as StddevM1, 0 AS StddevM2
    FROM M1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 0, STDEV(M2.Close)
    FROM M2
) q;
```

On second thought, one could actually use a CROSS JOIN here ;)

```
SELECT q1.M1, q2.M2
FROM (SELECT STDEV([Close]) as M1 FROM M1) q1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT STDEV([Close]) as M2 FROM M2) q2;
```

Answer (score -1):

I understand what you guys are saying, but i just want to understand more how SQL works behind

if

```
from A, B
```

has the same result as

```
from A cross join B
```

then why

```
select STDEV(M1.[Close]) as M1 from M1, M2;
```

process so quickly, but

```
select STDEV(M1.[Close]) as M1, STDEV(M2.[Close]) as M2 from M1, M2;
```

takes forever?

both queries need to multiple 2 tables first.

Comment: I'm guessing the sql optimizer just gets rid of M2 in your fast example because it knows it won't need it